# How to trigger [php] scripts on error finding images with Apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

I have an issue where we have image loading up from various html sources and straight image requests and a "File does not exist" is occurring.  Unfortunately this is due to a number of images that have been resized / cached were destroyed during a cache clean on this app and therefore have to be regenerated.  Straight http requests for the smaller images simply return an error as Apache knows no differently other than that the file is gone.

I would like to write a script that will regenerate these images if there is an error.  In other words, an error is triggered and then a script is called to regenerate the image in question from the original if that particular original image is requested and then that cached image will then be served.  How would one go about setting this up with httpd?

This is a snippet of the error log:

```
[Mon Apr 15 13:51:36 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/180x180/4da38bab36523d0886e53b8d57126395/h/k/hk0412.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 13:57:24 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/4da38bab36523d0886e53b8d57126395/n/c/nca20212.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 13:57:47 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/4da38bab36523d0886e53b8d57126395/v/z/vz0612.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 13:58:42 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/220x220/4da38bab36523d0886e53b8d57126395/R/A/RA01112.jpg
```

Comment: you could set all jpg\gif requests to go to a php script that would serve the file if exists or create otherwise. don't know if its the best idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the request URL includes for example `/cache/images/abc.jpg`, you can rewrite to some PHP script, if it doesn't exist

```
# if the file exists, just send it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^cache/image/.*$ - [L]

# if it doesn't exists, rewrite to PHP script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^cache/image/.*$ /path/to/script.php?url=$0 [L]
```

The `script.php` regenerates the image and sends it to the client.

Comment: There is no need to put the url in the query string. The script will know the requested url from $_SERVER, and you do not mess with any other query strings that might be attached. Otherwise, make sure to use [L,QSA] for the rewrite rule if you not only change the path, but also the query string.

Comment: So guys, [here's an example](https://gist.github.com/ylluminate/b17430c126f576ec9ab8/raw/f9774a55105e5251144dfab951e1b81ac00bbc8f/gistfile1.txt) of the output within the error_log from apache for some instances of images that need to be regenerated.  What are your thoughts on the specifics of matching these in the regex most efficiently as @Sven has explained?

Comment: @ylluminate It's up to you, which way you prefer. Both, using a query string or asking `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, are viable and legitimate ways accessing a request URL. For adding `QSA`, it doesn't hurt. But I think, it's also an artificial, academic point, because image URL requests usually don't carry query strings. If you do have such requests, and the query strings have some meaning beyond versioning, @Sven is right and you must add `QSA` of course.

Answer (score 2):

If an image is not there, Apache will trigger a 404 error page you can use for this purpose. You might want to avoid triggering a PHP script on every request, or having to check the files existance with a rewrite rule.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /reCacheImage.php
```

Put something like this in the configuration, either in a directory container in your vhost, or in a .htaccess inside the directory that has images missing. There is no need to answer all 404 situations with your script if they are not requesting any images.

Your script can then create the cached version, store in to disk and also send status 200 and the created image itself back to the browser. It should not be called when the image is requested next time.